# PDFKit Node.js measurement unit

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

What is the measurement unit used in PDFKit (Node.js)? For example we use:

```
doc.text(20, 20, 'Message')
```

What does `20(x)` and `20(x)` stand for? Is it centimeter, millimeter, inch? Can I change it to any familiar format like `cm`, `mm`, or `inch`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As most PDF generators *(if not any)*, PDFKit uses [**points**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)) too as stated in the official documentation under the [**Adding pages**](http://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html#adding_pages) section as **PDF Points**:

> The layout property can be either portrait (the default) or landscape. The size property can be either an array specifying [width, height] **in PDF points (72 per inch)**, or a string specifying a predefined size. A list of the predefined paper sizes can be seen here. The default is letter.
>
> ...
>
> You can set the page margins in two ways. The first is by setting the margin property (singular) to a number, which applies that margin to all edges. The other way is to set the margins property (plural) to an object with top, bottom, left, and right values. **The default is a 1 inch (72 point)** margin on all sides.

**This unit is not only applicable, when specifying the layout dimensions, but also, when any type of numbered unit is used to modify the generated PDF.** *(e.g. drawing text, images, vectors, etc.)*

---

Since [**PDF**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF) is derived from [**PostScript**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript), it uses internally the same graphics model too including the same basic measurement unit as PostScript, which is [**points**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript#Units_of_length) *(`72 points == 1 inch`)*. This measurement unit is the **device-independent way of using and stating dimensions**.

---

**You cannot change PDFKit's measurement unit.** In order to use other units rather, than points, you have to calculate yourself the unit and **multiply by a factor according to points**. Since you are **not bound to integer points**, you can use **floats, when specifying points** too (e.g.: `100.15`).

---

### Example:

If you use an **A4**-sized page (which is `8.27 × 11.69 inches` or `210 × 297 mm`), its dimensions are rounded off to `595 × 842 points` (`pt` in short):

- `1pt` is `~0.35mm`, or `~0.04cm`
- `10pt` is `~3.53mm`, or `~0.35cm`
- `100pt` is `~35.28mm`, or `~3.53cm`
- `148.75pt` (quarter page width) is `~52.48mm` or `~5.25cm`
- `297.5pt` (half page width) is `~104.95mm` or `~10.50cm`

In case you need pixels, you have to base your calculations by a specific **DPI** too, so the size in pixels of an **A4**-sized page with:

- `72 DPI` is `595 x 842px`
- `96 DPI` is `794 x 1123px`
- `150 DPI` is `1240 x 1754px`
- `300 DPI` is `2480 x 3508px`

---

For starters, here is a simple script listing the basic units and their values after converting to points you have mentioned:

```js
function mmToPt (mm) {
  return mm * 2.83465;
}

function cmToPt (cm) {
  return cm * 28.3465;
}

function inchToPt (inch) {
  return inch * 72;
}

const units = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
  5,
  10,
  15,
  20,
  25,
  50,
  100,
  150,
  250,
  500,
  1000
];

function convert (unit) {
  let name;
  let converter;
  
  switch (unit) {
    case 'mm':
      name = 'millimeters';
      converter = mmToPt;
      break;
    
    case 'cm':
      name = 'centimeters';
      converter = cmToPt;
      break;
      
    case 'inch':
      name = 'inches';
      converter = inchToPt;
      break;
  }
  
  console.log(`Convert ${name} to points:`);
  
  units.forEach(u => {
    let converted = converter(u).toFixed(2);
    
    // get rid of unneeded .00 decimals
    if (+converted === parseInt(converted, 10)) {
      converted = +converted;
    }
    
    console.log(`${u}${unit} is ${converted}pt, so in doc.text(${converted}, ${converted}, 'Message')`);
  });
  
  console.log('--------------------------------------------');
}

convert('mm');
convert('cm');
convert('inch');
```

[**You can find a table of paper sizes with corresponding dimensions in points.**](https://www.prepressure.com/library/paper-size) This table is applicable to PDFKit and to most *(if not any)* of the PDF generators too.

Comment: Regarding your _"if not any"_ remark: jsPDF uses millimeters (mm) by default.